# If $T: \Bbb R^{3} \to P^{2}$ where $T(a,b) = (a-b)t^2 + (-a+b)$, is $T$ a matrix transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Called with $P^{2}$ the set of polynomials of degree at most $2$,

I know that a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^{n}$ to $\Bbb R^{n}$ is a linear transformation by solving the two properties of a linear transformation, but I'm confused on whether $\mathbb{R}^{3} \to  P^{2}$ would be a matrix transformation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How do you define “matrix transformation”?

Comment: Did you mean linear transformation?

Comment: It is certainly a *linear* transformation, and such a linear transformation between finite dimensional vector spaces *can* be represented as a matrix.  The punchline here though is that you will have to interpret the column vector of the result differently in order to interpret it as an element of $P^2$.  Rather than a $3$-tuple you interpret it as a polynomial with those coefficients.

Comment: Differ: $T:\Bbb R \color{red}{\to}P^2$ vs. $T(a,b,c)\color{red}{\mapsto}(a-b)t^2$

Answer (score 1):

It will be a linear transformation.

For it to be a linear transformation it should be closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Taking an example the linear transformation $L(x,y)=2x+y$, to confirm it's linear transformation we should have:

1.$\alpha L(x,y)=L(\alpha x,\alpha y)$ (closed under scalar multiplication)

2.$L(x,y)+L(a,b)=L[(x,y)+(a,b)]=L(x+a,y+b)$ (closed under addition)

The dimensions you're moving between say nothing about it being a linear transformation.

Considering your main question, polynomials of degree $n$ are in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

$\mathbb{P}^2$ is basically the same as $\mathbb{R}^3$ since a standard polynomial is it is of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ which has $3$ elements.

I will leave verifying the transformation in your question as linear as an exercise for you to have fun with, it should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not familiar with $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$ (The vectorial space of polynomials with real coefficients of degree at most $2$) you can prove that, fixed a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$, $ []_{\mathcal{B} }:\mathbb{R}_{2}[x] \longmapsto \mathbb{R}^{3}$ defined as $[p] = (a_{0},\cdots,a_{n})$, where $(a_{0},\cdots,a_{n})$ are the coefficients of $p \in \mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$, defines an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$ and $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

(This could be generalized of course to $\mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$)

Now you can think working between familiar vectorial spaces such as $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ up to isomorphism and write down the usual matrix trasformation associated to $T$.